# Specify pages to print with the "PrintPreviewAndPrint" method

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run the command Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint") to open the default Excel print preview and specify which pages should be printed. Is this possible? Because all the suggestions I found on the internet open a different print viewer.

To open the official Excel viewer I use this and it works:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
```

But with it I can't specify the pages I want to print.

With the code below I can specify the pages but it is a very different preview that does not seem to be the official Excel:

```
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
```

Is it possible to merge the two options? Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint") and specify which pages should be printed?

Comment: As far as I know, the Printer Settings cannot be manipulated with the Excel application. Only the Windows Shell can communicate to the printer, which you may be able to accomplish in VBA, but I have no advice on how to do so. Talking about what you can accomplish in Excel, you could just trim the `PageSetup.PrintArea` to the desired pages, and then return it to the full document later.

Answer (score 0):

In your first command you can define the pages.

[image: See picture]